# Convert XSD to RDF Schema

Tags: xsd, rdfs

Is there a tool for generate RDFS from an XSD?

Answer (score 7):

One option is a so-called **lifting** tool that converts a XML schema (XSD) to a RDF schema, such as RDFS or OWL. One such tool is [XML2OWL](http://xml2owl.sourceforge.net/index.php) (from an XML instance document or XSD), or [XSD2OWL](http://rhizomik.net/html/redefer/#XSD2OWL) (from XSD).

Another option is to use [TopBraid Composer](http://www.topquadrant.com/products/TB_Composer.html), and an [XSD to OWL plugin](http://www.incunabulum.de/projects/it/xsdimport) (however note that this is commercial software).

MIT Simile list some more ["RDF-izers"](http://simile.mit.edu/wiki/RDFizers) which might interest you.

Comment: It looks like the XML2OWL tool is broken--at least from the web interface.

Comment: The MIT Simile link is dead.